# Safe storage of blender blades

Tags: storage

I bought a couple replacement blades for an Osterizer blender, to find something that's better for smoothies.  My wife stuck them in the knife drawer, as I discovered when I went to find a pizza cutter.

[image]

Note that the "knife drawer" holds all sorts of cutting and bladed utensils, and I currently have other dedicated places for "good" knives; but when I did have good knives stored there I put then in cardboard sheathes.  The pizza cutter and some other tools come with their own sheathes.  Other things don't need it.

But these things are wicked, and I don't want to rummage around in the drawer with those ready to catch a finger! And, other tools may ding the sharp edges.

They are not flat, so a scrap of folded cardboard and binder clip won't do.  What's a good way to protect these in a drawer?

Comment: Not sure what dimensions your blades are, but maybe for a quick fix, just put an old can over it provided it fits in the drawer

Comment: I put them inside the blender bowl

Answer (score 5):

If you have the plastic top from a spray can of paint, you could insert the sharp end of the blades into it. Use some tape or cling wrap to keep the top on the blades.

You could also use a paper cup, but it may not last long in a drawer.

Comment: I would also consider taking the blade to something like "The Container Store" and seeing if there's some low-profile circular container that would work.

Answer (score 5):

Osterizer™ blades exactly fit the standard regular-mouth "Mason" jar dimensions. They were part of the standard sizes agreed upon by manufacturers of canning and food processing equipment back in 1868. This is a "good thing™."

Mason™ jars are also known by other names such as Ball, Bocal, Bernadin, Kerr, Crown, Corona, and others. They are commonly available in almost all supermarkets, hardware stores, and garden stores in North America.

Place the sharp blades **face-down** *inside* a small mason preserves jar and screw the rim closed to secure the blades inside safe and clean, nick free. You don't need the insert since the base of the blades is the same size. You can choose to leave it in to cover the bottom of the blender blade assembly.

[image: Nesting blades inside "mason" jar]

Use a small jar for each of the blades you don't keep in the container itself.

TIP: You can use "mason" jars on your Osterizer blender directly as the container for your sauces, smoothies, and blends. There's no cleanup of the unnecessary regular glass pitcher-jar.

Answer (score 2):

store them in a transparent plastic or glass big nose bottle with cap in the same compartment you store the blender.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could try is using some thick tape that isn't easily cuttable, such as electric tape. Wrap it backwards (sticky side out) around the blade, but not too tightly. Once you have it fully wrapped, you can then wrap it the other way to cover the sticky part. Once wrapped both ways, it should still be flexible, and should fit around the blade nicely. And it's probably about as sanitary as cardboard, but you should probably at least rinse it with hot water before using.